Trisection of 60 degree angle
I created a construction for a trisection of a 60-degree angle. I know this is false, so where did I mess up?
First, we draw line AB. We then construct an equilateral triangle ABC from side AB (valid construction). Next, we bisect angle (valid construction) C and extend it to meet AB at M. We bisect angle ACM and extend it to meet AB at D. Because angle C = 60, bisecting into ACM and BCM makes them both equal to 30. Bisecting ACM into ACD and DCM makes them both equal to 15. Thus, DCB = 45. We repeat this process on angle B.
We have now created a 45-45-90 triangle (both angles are 45, the only possibility for the third is 90). The 90-degree angle is at point x. Now we zoom out. To trisect an isosceles triangle, we trisect the side CB. Since we created a 45-45-90 triangle on side CB, we can trisect this triangle's hypotenuse, which is also CB. If we create another equilateral triangle on XB, where the equilateral triangle intersects the right triangle at X, B, and a new point, H. Now, we have that XCH is 30 degrees. We then bisect the equilateral triangle, trisecting the 90-degree angle, thus trisecting CB. the trisectors meet line CB at points H and Y. We draw lines AH and AY. Isn't that a 20 degree angle? (there are other proofs for different assumptions)

I can share a diagram and proofs for the assumptions if needed, but my computer is really slow.

I haven’t read through your proof but constructing a 20 degree is possible. Trisecting angles in general can’t be done but it can be done for special cases. Like 15,30,60

What's impossible is "a method that can trisect any given angle." What's not impossible is to come up with methods for trisecting particular angles.

@Euclid but is this trisection possible with classic tools?

@AdamDougall  no,  the minimal polynomial for $x = 2 \cos 40^\circ$  is $x^3 - 3 x + 1.$   So $40^\circ$ is not constructible, and $20^\circ$ isn't either

The $20^\circ$ angle is not constructible. See, for instance, the "Proof of impossibility" section of Wikipedia's "Angle Trisection" entry. ... It's hard to say where your attempt goes wrong. I get stuck at the step where you construct the equilateral triangle on $XB$: "the equilateral triangle intersects the right triangle at X, B, and a new point, H". I don't understand where $H$ is supposed to be. A diagram would really help here. (Also, separating the steps into a numbered list might make them easier to follow.)

Yes apologies, I didn’t verify the result from my quick google but you are quite correct. 20 degrees is not constructible.

Can you explain this line more: “Since we created a 45-45-90 triangle on side CB, we can trisect this triangle's hypotenuse”

Using side CB, we constructed a 45-45-90 triangle where CB was the hypotenuse.

If we divide a 45 45 90 degree triangle's right angle into a 30 degree part and a 60 degree part, the line that separates the two intersects the hypotenuse at point H.

You trisected the angle BXC, not the side CB. And angle HAY according to your construction measures a little less than $17.59^\circ$. See https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/e4583szk

"the line that separates [the 30 degree part and the 60 degree part of the right angle] intersects the hypotenuse at point H" ... Then, should(n't) you have written that angle $CXH$ is 30 degrees instead of angle $XCH$?

You're ultimately assuming that the trisectors of $\angle BAC$ and $\angle BXC$ meet $BC$ at the same pts, $H$ and $Y$. (If so, then the easy trisection of rt $\angle BXC$ gives us a trisection of $\angle BAC$ for free.) Unfortunately, the assumption is incorrect in general. (As @DavidK notes, it isn't even terribly close here, with a constructed $\sim 17.6^\circ$ angle vs the target $20^\circ$.) A bit of trig shows that, for $P$ on the perp bisector of $BC$ $$\frac{|HY|}{|BC|}=\frac{\tan\frac16\angle BPC}{\tan\frac12\angle BPC}$$ which gives different values for different angles.

Basically , this is wrong "To trisect an isosceles triangle, we trisect the side CB" which you should try to recheck more carefully. Diagram will make it easier to visualize while communicating.

Is Trisecting or getting the Value of Third of an angle the same?
